# Install development tool on the Linux Cent os, which doesnt have Internet

Tags: linux, centos, development-environment, nagios, nrpe

I have to install NRPE Nagios Plugin on the Linux cent os Server which doesn't have the internet.

so i have downloaded the TAR files and copied to the Linux server(which has no internet) but i can't complie it because i am getting this error while Compiling it.
[image]
[image]

I think i am missing some Developements tool for the Server, I can easily download all this development tools on the server which has Internet with yum `install package name` but my Issue is i cannot have the Internet on that particular machine where i am trying to install the NRPE.

can someone please Help me out , Thanks In advance.

Comment: You dont have to install NRPE from tar. NRPE rpm is in `EPEL` repo.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `gcc` or if you have it installed, you need to add it to the `$PATH`.

Comment: I know i have to but my problem is How can i install it to the machine which is having no Internet

Comment: You would need to download the `gcc` package on a machine with internet connection and then, use a media(like usb) to transfer the downloaded package to this machine and install it locally.

Comment: can you be bit specific with Linux Command Please

Comment: On a Linux machine with internet connection:
1. `yum install yum-utils`
2. `yumdownloader gcc gcc-c++` 

The above command will download the packages for you. Now copy these packages to the machine with no internet connection via some media and run:

`sudo yum --nogpgcheck localinstall <packages>`

Install the downloaded packages may ask for more dependencies and you would need to repeat the same process 1. Download the dependency packages 2. Copy them to the machine with no internet connection. 3. Install them passing all the package names to the `yum localinstall ...` command.

Comment: Can you please write here commands

Comment: so i have copied the packages to the Cent os Machine but i am getting this error while installing it.
`yum localinstall gcc-c++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64.rpm           Loaded plugins: presto, product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Local Package Process

cannot open: gcc-c++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64.rpm. skipping`

Comment: Did you download both the packages? gcc and gcc-c++ ? and passed both the packages to `yum localinstall` command?

Comment: yum localinstall gcc-c++-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64.rpm gcc-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64.rpm

still the same issue

Comment: I have tried also with these command but still the same issue

Comment: Looks like it is a RedHat machine? 
Try this `sudo vi /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/subscription-manager.conf` and change the enabled=0 to enabled=1 in the file and try that `yum localinstall` command again. Use sudo for this `yum localinstall` command.

Comment: i have solved the otehr problem but now i am having some other dependencies problem, as you have already told me to do so

Comment: I think, Yes! Also, you can try install only `gcc` first and then its dependencies. 
gcc-c++ can be installed later.

Comment: `checking for SSL headers... configure: error: Cannot find ssl headers` i could install the GCC and everything but while `./configure ` i get this error

Comment: You need to install the openssl packages now. I think, the package name is `openssl-devel` - Give it a try. You need to follow the same process.

Comment: That is Crazy , now there are so many other pacakages i need to install

Comment: I agree. It is hard to install packages on a machine which is offline.